# Only glClear(..) color is displayed, nothing else rendered (CUDA/OpenGL interop)

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda

I have a WinForms application with a panel (500x500 pixels) that I want to render something in. At this point I am just trying to fill it in with a specific color. I want to use OpenGL/CUDA interop to do this.

I got the panel configured to be the region to render stuff in, however when I run my code, the panel just gets filled with the glClear(..) color, and nothing assigned by the kernel is displayed. It sort of worked this morning (inconsistently), and in my attempt to sort out the SwapBuffers() mess, I think I screwed it up.

Here is the pixel format initialization for OpenGL. It seems to work fine, I have the two buffers as I expected, and the context is correct:

```
static  PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd=              
{
    sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),              // Size Of This Pixel Format Descriptor
    1,                                          // Version Number
    PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |                        // Format Must Support Window
    PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |                        // Format Must Support OpenGL
    PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,                           // Must Support Double Buffering
    PFD_TYPE_RGBA,                              // Request An RGBA Format
    16,                                         // Select Our Color Depth
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                           // Color Bits Ignored
    0,                                          // No Alpha Buffer
    0,                                          // Shift Bit Ignored
    0,                                          // No Accumulation Buffer
    0, 0, 0, 0,                                 // Accumulation Bits Ignored
    16,                                         // 16Bit Z-Buffer (Depth Buffer) 
    0,                                          // No Stencil Buffer
    0,                                          // No Auxiliary Buffer
    PFD_MAIN_PLANE,                             // Main Drawing Layer
    0,                                          // Reserved
    0, 0, 0                                     // Layer Masks Ignored
};

GLint  iPixelFormat; 

// get the device context's best, available pixel format match 
if((iPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd)) == 0)
{
    MessageBox::Show("ChoosePixelFormat Failed");
    return 0;
}

// make that match the device context's current pixel format 
if(SetPixelFormat(hdc, iPixelFormat, &pfd) == FALSE)
{
    MessageBox::Show("SetPixelFormat Failed");
    return 0;
}

if((m_hglrc = wglCreateContext(m_hDC)) == NULL)
{
    MessageBox::Show("wglCreateContext Failed");
    return 0;
}

if((wglMakeCurrent(m_hDC, m_hglrc)) == NULL)
{
    MessageBox::Show("wglMakeCurrent Failed");
    return 0;
}
```

After this is done, I set up the ViewPort as such:

```
glViewport(0,0,iWidth,iHeight);                     // Reset The Current Viewport
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);                         // Select The Modelview Matrix
glLoadIdentity();                                   // Reset The Modelview Matrix
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Then I set up the clear color and do a clear:

```
glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT| GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Now I set up the CUDA/OpenGL interop:

```
cudaDeviceProp prop; int dev;
memset(&prop, 0, sizeof(cudaDeviceProp));
prop.major = 1; prop.minor = 0;

checkCudaErrors(cudaChooseDevice(&dev, &prop));
checkCudaErrors(cudaGLSetGLDevice(dev));

glBindBuffer    = (PFNGLBINDBUFFERARBPROC)GET_PROC_ADDRESS("glBindBuffer");
glDeleteBuffers = (PFNGLDELETEBUFFERSARBPROC)GET_PROC_ADDRESS("glDeleteBuffers");
glGenBuffers    = (PFNGLGENBUFFERSARBPROC)GET_PROC_ADDRESS("glGenBuffers");
glBufferData    = (PFNGLBUFFERDATAARBPROC)GET_PROC_ADDRESS("glBufferData");

GLuint bufferID;
cudaGraphicsResource * resourceID;

glGenBuffers(1, &bufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, bufferID);
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, fWidth*fHeight*4, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW_ARB);

checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer( &resourceID, bufferID, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsNone ));
```

Now I try to call my kernel (which just paints each pixel a specific color) and have that displayed.

```
uchar4* devPtr;
size_t size;

// First clear the back buffer:
glClearColor(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // orange
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &resourceID, NULL));
checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer((void**)&devPtr, &size, resourceID));

animate(devPtr); // This will call the kernel and do a sync (see later)

checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &resourceID, NULL));

// Swap buffers to bring back buffer forward:
SwapBuffers(m_hDC);
```

At this point I expect to see the kernel colors on the screen, but no! I see orange, which is the clear color that I just set.

Here is the call to the kernel:

```
void animate(uchar4* dispPtr)
{
    checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    animKernel<<<blocks, threads>>>(dispPtr, envdim);;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
}
```

Here `envdim` is just the dimensions (so 500x500). The kernel itself:

```
__global__ void animKernel(uchar4 *optr, dim3 matdim)
{
    int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    int offset = x + y * matdim.x;

    if (x < matdim.x && y < matdim.y)
    {
        // BLACK:
        optr[offset].x = 0; optr[offset].y = 0; optr[offset].z = 0;
    }
}
```

Things I've done:

- The value returned by cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer's `size` is 1000000, which corresponds to the 500x500 matrix of uchar4, so that's good.
- Each kernel printed the value and location that it was writing to, and that seemed ok.
- Played with the alpha value for the clear color, but that doesn't seem to do anything (yet?)
- Ran the animate() function several times. Don't know why I thought that would help, but I tried it...

So I guess I'm missing something, but I'm going kind of crazy looking for it. Any advice? Help?

Comment: Oh right, I forgot how trigger happy SO is with the close votes. This is literally the minimal amount of code to demonstrate the problem. I put effort into this code and the question. I am missing something, and I don't know what anymore. I've searched SO and Google for an answer, and I haven't found anything. I've explained my thought process in code and comments.

Comment: Could you combine all the disparate code snippets into an actual complete repro case with a concrete question?

Comment: I think the description of MCVE is pretty clear.  Your code is not complete.  If you don't want to provide an MCVE, that's your call.  Here's the thing:  if I wanted to help you, the first thing I would want to do is run your code. If your code is 80% complete, I have to fill in the 20%, with code that I dream up but **you have already written** but chosen not to show.  That doesn't strike me as the best way to get help.  Why not provide something that I can copy, paste, compile and run? You've already written the code, right?  Minimal doesn't mean **less than Complete**.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, because last time I did this, I was told that noone was going to try running my code, and that it was too much to expect. This isn't a single file project. Furthermore, the project itself requires adding a custom build (to handle CUDA within the WinForms), navigating to a variety of header file location, changing the project from /clr:pure to /clr. Don't get me wrong, I can post the code that I've already written for this program (or the entire project while I'm at it), but then I'll get downvoted even more for posting a ton of code...

Comment: Because if you did that, then the example is not **M**inimal. You've included extra junk that's not necessary to see the issue. Just to pick an example, if you did something weird with `threads`, it's possible your kernel is not running at all **and** your kernel error checking happens to be broken so it would not catch that error. So of course I could ask you to show your definition of `threads`. Then we go onto the next thing.  Do you want someone to play 20 questions with you to tease out the details of your code?  It's inefficient, and the MCVE description was written to help address that.

Comment: Creating an MCVE from a large project is hard.  You have to distill things down and essentially write a new application, and test it yourself.  If you don't, it's probably niether **C**omplete nor **V**erifiable.  Yes!!! It requires effort on your part.  Without that effort to write a good question, you're more likely to get downvoted.  And if your question asks for debugging help but obviously doesn't contain an MCVE, then I think MCVE close votes are reasonable to expect.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, I actually **have** another project, and I **have** been putting effort into this. Trust me, asking questions on SO is not an enjoyable experience for me. My projects aren't small enough to  "distill" it down to a file. The moment I start with a WinForms application, that already has a form, and a panel - this on its own is a big file full of text, but is necessary! Then add my kernel files, that, while empty, are separate files. Then add all of the OpenGL stuff that I have in a separate class - that's another file. Then the properties file for the project...

Comment: @RobertCrovella, I think the issue is something bloody trivial in the code I posted. Something probably to do with a parameter in one of the initialization functions. Secondly, I already mentioned that I know my kernel runs and writes the correct values to the array pointed to by `optr`.

Comment: OK we can agree to disagree.  You at least have a description of the rationale behind my voting.  I understand you don't agree with it. (However I think it's solidly based on the information I read about SO expectations.)  Your question is not actually closed unless 5 such votes are cast.  Maybe someone will spot the error.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, might as well just delete it now :( I am probably better off rewriting the entire project from scratch than asking anything on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's another one of those questions I answer myself! Hmph, as I figured, it was a one line issue.  The problem resides in the rendering call itself.

The configuration is fine, the one issue I have with the code above is:
**I never called `glDrawPixels()`**, which is necessary in order for the OpenGL driver to copy the shared buffer (`GL_PiXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB`) source to the display buffer. The correct rendering sequence is then:

```
uchar4* devPtr;
size_t size;

// First clear the back buffer:
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &resourceID, NULL));
checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer((void**)&devPtr, &size, resourceID));

animate(devPtr); // This will call the kernel and do a sync (see later)

checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &resourceID, NULL));

// This is necessary to copy the shared buffer to display
glDrawPixels(fWidth, fHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

// Swap buffers to bring back buffer forward:
SwapBuffers(m_hDC);
```

I'd like to thank the Acade-- uh, CUDA By Example, once again for helping me. Even though the example code from the book used GLUT (which was completely useless for this...), the book referenced normal gl functions.

Comment: Note that `glDrawPixels()` is a deprecated function that is not available anymore in the OpenGL Core Profile. It's very obsolete, and I wouldn't count on it being efficient on current systems. If you care about performance, you may want to look for another way to render your data.

Comment: @RetoKoradi, thanks for the suggestion. I got the info from the book, so as long as it works for my project, I am probably fine with it. I'd be interested in hearing other suggestions though, and I will look for some myself.

Comment: @RetoKoradi, oh I see, looks like I should just use textured quads. I'll try this tomorrow.

Comment: @RetoKoradi, I did the textured quads today and there isn't any difference timing wise really. In fact textured quads are a tad bit slower than `glDrawPixels()`.

Comment: I'll eat my words, it's a bit faster with textured quads. About 3.3ms per frame vs 4.5ms per frame with `glDrawPixels()`.